# Xamarin Forms ImageButton gets smaller after changing Source dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

I have 3 ImageButton's on "Languages Page" that represent the 3 different languages of the application (Android).

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="flagsImageButtonStyles" TargetType="ImageButton">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest"
                    Value="130" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest"
                    Value="130" />
            <Setter Property="Aspect" Value="AspectFill" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    ...

    <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" StyleId="fr" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnFrench" Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource flagsImageButtonStyles}"/>
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" StyleId="nl" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnDutch" Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource flagsImageButtonStyles}"/>
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" StyleId="en" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnEnglish" Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource flagsImageButtonStyles}"/>

</Grid>
```

I set the Source of ImageButtons like this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        switch (CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName) // "fr", "nl", "en"
        {
            case "fr":
                btnFrench.Source = "fr_flag_selected.png";
                btnDutch.Source = "nl_flag.png";
                btnEnglish.Source = "en_flag.png";
                break;

            case "nl":
                btnFrench.Source = "fr_flag.png";
                btnDutch.Source = "nl_flag_selected.png";
                btnEnglish.Source = "en_flag.png";
                break;

            case "en":
                btnFrench.Source = "fr_flag.png";
                btnDutch.Source = "nl_flag.png";
                btnEnglish.Source = "en_flag_selected.png";
                break;
        }
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Whenever I click one of them, I set the language, and navigate to another page.

So next time the "Languages Page" is loaded, it will check for the current language and adapt the Source's of the ImageBUtton's.

The problem is that, whenever I click one of the ImageButton's or if the application goes to sleep, the ImageButton's get VERY SMALL.

Any idea, what might be wrong ?

Comment: try setting a height/width request value on the images

Comment: I already do this, in the styles above

Comment: Out of curosity why do you have three columns and only the second one is auto?

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed.

I had to specify the same Height/Width request that I apply to the ImageButton's, to rows and columns definitions:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="130"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```